# Insert/Update Table Locks on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, partitioning

I have a big table with around 70 columns in SQL Server 2008. A multithreaded .NET application is calling a stored proc on database to insert into / update the table. Frequency is around **3 times a second.**

I have made weekly partitions on table since almost every query has a `datetime` constraint on the table.

Sometimes it takes a long time to insert/update the table. I am suspicious that sometimes INSERTION makes UPDATE wait; sometimes UPDATE makes INSERTION wait. Is it possible?

How can I design the table to avoid such locks? Performance is the main issue here.

Comment: Is it possible to bulk-insert entries? If so you can accumulate the values for a minute and do a bulk insert. Also check if there are any performance intensive operation performed in triggers on that table.

Comment: Bulk insert is not possible. Because every single record is received by a web service call

Comment: How frequently is the table being read?? If the table is read frequently, you might consider "noLock" on select queries. Similarly if updates are not going to be performed based on the same primary key, you might consider nolock in update/insert as well.

Comment: @Vivek Table is being too much frequently. All select queries are with NOLOCK. Select is not problem.How can I perform NOLOCK Insert/Update?

Comment: UPDATE Product WITH (NOLock)
SET price=10
WHERE id=20

Comment: Similarly you can use "with (NOLock)" after table name in insert query as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Vivek - Using `nolock` in that manner has no effect. `X` locks are always needed for updates, inserts.

Comment: SQL Error:
The NOLOCK and READUNCOMMITTED lock hints are not allowed for target tables of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statements.

Comment: @AhmetAltun - How many rows are you inserting/updating at a time? How long do the statements usually take? How long do they take when performance seems noticeably slower? Probably worth setting up something to poll the waitstats DMVs to see what the wait is on when you get these delays.

Comment: @Martin - you are right.
Try setting the lock level to row lock for the update query

Answer (score -1):

You're right that you're probably hitting deadlocks causing things to wait. A couple things to check first;

1. Are your indexes correct?
2. If your DB is in 'Full' recovery mode do you need it? Simple recovery really speeds up inserts/updates, but you loose point-in-time restores for backups.
3. Are you likely to have multiple threads writing the same record? If not, NOLOCK might be your friend here, but that would mean your data might be inconsitent for a second or two on occasion.

Comment: NOLOCK hint is *not* available for insert/update "READPAST, NOLOCK, and READUNCOMMITTED are not allowed" (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662(v=sql.80).aspx)